# iOS: Start processing of Push notification in background?

Tags: ios, ipad, background, push-notification

what is the normal way to go about dealing with a Push notification that arrives when the recipient app is not already running? I am under the impression when the app starts, I can detect that it was started because a Push notification arrived, and then start downloading in the background without ever starting the GUI. But what do people normally do if the user starts an app when that downloading is happening? Just display a warning or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I am under the impression that I could start the app

That's a poor choice of words. *You* cannot do anything. The user may decide to open your app after receiving the push notification.

> detect that it was started because a Push notification arrived

Yep. application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in your app delegate will pass in a dictionary containing push notification data (in this case, the example code is a local notification):

```
if ([UILocalNotification class]) // check if we support local notifications
    {
        UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

        if (notification) {
            NSString *resourcePath = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"resourcePath"]; // get arbitrary data that you stored in the notification (key-value pairs)
        }

        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; // reset the app icon badge number
    }
```

> in the background without ever starting the GUI

You can't do that. The only possible workflow for app launch is notification->user taps read more button->app opens in the foreground.

> what do people normally do if the user starts an app when that downloading is happening? Just display a warning or something?

This question doesn't really apply since the app can't be started in the background, but in general users shouldn't care about what's happening if your app is doing something under the covers. Therefore, there should be no warning of any kind unless the data is required for the app to function.